# array/matrix specify default alignment

Tags: amsmath, matrices, arrays, alignment

normally you write a matrix something like this

```
\begin{align*}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        ele1 & ele2 & ele3 \\
        longEle1 & longEle2 & longEle3
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
```

the elements inside the matrix now will be centred to each other. With this little patch

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][*\c@MaxMatrixCols c]{
    \hskip -\arraycolsep
    \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
    \array{#1}
}
\makeatother
```

one is able to write matrices like this:

```
\begin{align*}
    \begin{pmatrix}[rrr]
        ele1 & ele2 & ele3 \\
        longEle1 & longEle2 & longEle3
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
```

and specify the alignment of the elements this way.

Now I'm searching for a way to redefine the default alignment in the array env (and therefore for matrices too) somehow.

From what I found out, it should be somewhere in the declaration of the `array.sty`, but up to now, I didn't found it.

I found only this paragraph in the array doc (see https://www.ctan.org/pkg/array, page 31):

> @tabarray
>
> This  macro  tests  for  an  optional  bracket  and  then  calls  up `\@@array` or `\@@array[c]` (as default).
>
> 343 `〈*package〉344\def\@tabarray{\@ifnextchar[{\@@array}{\@@array[c]}}`

But changing this line in the `/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty` (in my version this was in line 324) didn't help.

Does someone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][*\c@MaxMatrixCols r]{%
    \hskip -\arraycolsep
    \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
    \array{#1}
}
\makeatother
```

All the columns will be of type `r` by default but we can still specify the preamble (eg. `ccc`).

Comment: Could you expand this, so that if necessary you can still specify the formatting?

Comment: I have changed my post.

Comment: Oh sorry that was stupid, didn't saw this little `c` in my own code, which I'd have to change. Thought this would be something that had to be set for the whole array environment. Thanks a lot.